How to visually adjust border radius for KonvaJS Rect during transformation?
I want to adjust visually the border radius for the rect, so it stays "the same" during transformation.
What happens is the border-radius get's stretched during transformation, and it visually does not keep the border looking the way it basically should.
Reproduce from it:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- USE DEVELOPMENT VERSION -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9.3.16/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Konva Transform Limits Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height,
  });

  var layer = new Konva.Layer();
  stage.add(layer);

  var rect = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 160,
    y: 60,
    width: 100,
    height: 90,
    fill: 'red',
    name: 'rect',
    stroke: 'black',
    cornerRadius: 8,
    strokeScaleEnabled: false,
    draggable: true,
  });
  layer.add(rect);

  var MAX_WIDTH = 600;
  // create new transformer
  var tr = new Konva.Transformer({
    boundBoxFunc: function (oldBoundBox, newBoundBox) {
      // "boundBox" is an object with
      // x, y, width, height and rotation properties
      // transformer tool will try to fit nodes into that box

      // the logic is simple, if new width is too big
      // we will return previous state
      if (Math.abs(newBoundBox.width) > MAX_WIDTH) {
        return oldBoundBox;
      }

      return newBoundBox;
    },
  });
  layer.add(tr);
  tr.nodes([rect]);
</script>
</body>
</html>


This looks weird when transforming:

I've tried to connect to the transform event:
rect.on("transform", () => {
const scaledRadius = originalCornerRadius / Math.max(rect.scaleX(), rect.scaleY());
rect.cornerRadius(scaledRadius);
 });


And adjust the radius but this doesnt seem to give me satisfied results.

I recommend resetting scaleX and scaleY and using only the width/height attributes for transformation.


var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height,
  });

  var layer = new Konva.Layer();
  stage.add(layer);

  var rect = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 160,
    y: 60,
    width: 100,
    height: 90,
    fill: 'red',
    name: 'rect',
    stroke: 'black',
    cornerRadius: 20,
    strokeScaleEnabled: false,
    draggable: true,
  });
  layer.add(rect);

  var MAX_WIDTH = 600;

  // create new transformer
  var tr = new Konva.Transformer({
    ignoreStroke: true,
    padding: 2,
    boundBoxFunc: function (oldBoundBox, newBoundBox) {
      if (Math.abs(newBoundBox.width) > MAX_WIDTH) {
        return oldBoundBox;
      }
      return newBoundBox;
    },
  });
  layer.add(tr);
  tr.nodes([rect]);

  // Correctly adjust dimensions and scale on transformation
  rect.on('transform', () => {
    // Get new scale
    const scaleX = rect.scaleX();
    const scaleY = rect.scaleY();

    // Update width and height based on scales
    rect.width(rect.width() * scaleX);
    rect.height(rect.height() * scaleY);

    // Reset scales
    rect.scaleX(1);
    rect.scaleY(1);
  });

  stage.draw();
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9.3.16/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>




This is what I've been looking for. Didn't really know resetting the scales would do the trick, thank you.
